# Spring boot metrics + datadog

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, datadog, metrics-spring

Does anyone know how to integrate Spring boot metrics with datadog?

[Datadog](https://www.datadoghq.com/) is a cloud-scale monitoring service for IT.

It allows users to easily visualice their data using a lot of charts and graphs.

I have a spring boot application that is using [dropwizard](http://www.dropwizard.io/) metrics to populate a lot of information about all methods I annotated with `@Timed`.

On the other hand I'm deploying my application in heroku so I can't install a Datadog agent.

I want to know if there is a way to automatically integrate spring boot metric system reporting with datadog.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've finally found a dropwizzard module that integrates this library with datadog: [metrics-datadog](https://github.com/coursera/metrics-datadog)

I've created a Spring configuration class that creates and initializes this Reporter using properties of my YAML.

Just insert this dependency in your pom:

```
    <!-- Send metrics to Datadog -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.coursera</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-metrics-datadog</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Add this configuration to your YAML:

```
yourapp:
  metrics:
    apiKey: <your API key>
    host: <your host>
    period: 10
    enabled: true
```

and add this configuration class to your project:

```
/**
 * This bean will create and configure a DatadogReporter that will be in charge of sending
 * all the metrics collected by Spring Boot actuator system to Datadog.
 *     
 * @see https://www.datadoghq.com/
 * @author jfcorugedo
 *
 */
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("yourapp.metrics")
public class DatadogReporterConfig {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DatadogReporterConfig.class);

  /** Datadog API key used to authenticate every request to Datadog API */
  private String apiKey;

  /** Logical name associated to all the events send by this application */
  private String host;

  /** Time, in seconds, between every call to Datadog API. The lower this value the more information will be send to Datadog */
  private long period;

  /** This flag enables or disables the datadog reporter */
  private boolean enabled = false;

  @Bean
  @Autowired
  public DatadogReporter datadogReporter(MetricRegistry registry) {

      DatadogReporter reporter = null;
      if(enabled) {
          reporter = enableDatadogMetrics(registry);
      } else {
          if(LOGGER.isWarnEnabled()) {
              LOGGER.info("Datadog reporter is disabled. To turn on this feature just set 'rJavaServer.metrics.enabled:true' in your config file (property or YAML)");
          }
      }

      return reporter;
  }

  private DatadogReporter enableDatadogMetrics(MetricRegistry registry) {

      if(LOGGER.isInfoEnabled()) {
          LOGGER.info("Initializing Datadog reporter using [ host: {}, period(seconds):{}, api-key:{} ]", getHost(), getPeriod(), getApiKey());
      }

      EnumSet<Expansion> expansions = DatadogReporter.Expansion.ALL;
      HttpTransport httpTransport = new HttpTransport
                                .Builder()
                                .withApiKey(getApiKey())
                                .build();

      DatadogReporter reporter = DatadogReporter.forRegistry(registry)
        .withHost(getHost())
        .withTransport(httpTransport)
        .withExpansions(expansions)
        .build();

      reporter.start(getPeriod(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);

      if(LOGGER.isInfoEnabled()) {
          LOGGER.info("Datadog reporter successfully initialized");
      }

      return reporter;
  }

  /**
   * @return Datadog API key used to authenticate every request to Datadog API
   */
  public String getApiKey() {
      return apiKey;
  }

  /**
   * @param apiKey Datadog API key used to authenticate every request to Datadog API
   */
  public void setApiKey(String apiKey) {
      this.apiKey = apiKey;
  }

  /**
   * @return Logical name associated to all the events send by this application
   */
  public String getHost() {
      return host;
  }

  /**
   * @param host Logical name associated to all the events send by this application
   */
  public void setHost(String host) {
      this.host = host;
  }

  /**
   * @return Time, in seconds, between every call to Datadog API. The lower this value the more information will be send to Datadog
   */
  public long getPeriod() {
      return period;
  }

  /**
   * @param period Time, in seconds, between every call to Datadog API. The lower this value the more information will be send to Datadog
   */
  public void setPeriod(long period) {
      this.period = period;
  }

  /**
   * @return true if DatadogReporter is enabled in this application
   */
  public boolean isEnabled() {
      return enabled;
  }

  /**
   * This flag enables or disables the datadog reporter.
   * This flag is only read during initialization, subsequent changes on this value will no take effect 
   * @param enabled
   */
  public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
      this.enabled = enabled;
  }
}
```

Comment: It is also possible to use the same library for StatsD reporting, instead of HTTP, should anybody be interested in that option.

Comment: Do you need to write a scheduler, because adding given resources is not working out for me.

Answer (score 7):

It seems that Spring Boot 2.x added several monitoring system into its metrics. DataDog is one of them supported by [micrometer.io](http://micrometer.io/). See reference documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html#production-ready-metrics-export-newrelic

For Spring Boot 1.x, you can use back-ported package:

`compile 'io.micrometer:micrometer-spring-legacy:latest.release'`

Comment: Hey is spring boot 2 working with datadog agent 5? since I have upgraded my application to spring boot 2 and now I don't get any metric in my datadog! do I need to change anything? I have heard datadog doesnt support netty I have problem with APM metrics

Comment: same problem here... spring boot 2 apps says it submits only jdbc and pool metrics and even those i cant see in the datadog gui.

Comment: @Marc, do you have management.metrics.export.datadog.enabled set to true? You might need to implement a metrics configuration and a meter service

Answer (score 2):

If JMX is an option for you, you may use the [JMX dropwizrd reporter](https://dropwizard.github.io/metrics/3.1.0/getting-started/#reporting-via-jmx) combined with [java datalog integration](http://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/java/)

Comment: That's a good point. However I'm deploying my app in heroku, so I can't install a datadog agent in the OS

Comment: @jfcorugedo I don't think the question mentioned anything about heroku? If heroku solution is needed, you'll need to add it to the question.

Comment: There appears to be a good economic argument for this way too - you get 350 metrics per instance for free. If your application pumps all it's metrics into DataDog (using `dropwizard-metrics-datadog` for instance) those metrics count toward your custom use limit - using the integration significantly lessens the impact.