# Datadog java agent and autodiscovery

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, datadog

I'll need to monitor java springboot containers on kubernetes.

I'll probably use the [installation process using helm](https://docs.datadoghq.com/fr/containers/kubernetes/installation/?tab=helm) to deploy the agent on the nodes.

I'll probably use the [annotations on pods](https://docs.datadoghq.com/getting_started/containers/autodiscovery/) to avoid configuration file managements

I saw in the documentation that there was a jar client that you can add to each pod to monitor the containers.

If I need to monitor a springboot application, do I have to install both the datadog agent on the nodes + the datadog agent on the pods to reach springboot
OR will the datadog agent on the nodes be allowed to monitor a springboot agent turning into a pod using only annotations and environnement variables ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Datadog come with deployment and daemonset

- cluster agent (for Kubernetes metrics) deployment
- daemonset (for traching and logs) daemonset

```
helm repo add datadog https://helm.datadoghq.com
helm repo update
helm install <RELEASE_NAME> -f values.yaml  --set datadog.apiKey=<DATADOG_API_KEY> datadog/datadog --set targetSystem=<TARGET_SYSTEM>
```

> This chart adds the Datadog Agent to all nodes in your cluster with a **DaemonSet**. It also optionally deploys the kube-state-metrics chart and uses it as an additional source of metrics about the cluster. A few minutes after installation, Datadog begins to report hosts and metrics.

**Logs:**
For logs and APM you need some extra config

```
datadog:
  logs:
    enabled: true
    containerCollectAll: true
```

[data-k8-logs-collection](https://docs.datadoghq.com/containers/kubernetes/log/?tab=helm)

Once everything is done, then its time to add auto-discovery
again no need to install anything for auto-discovery, until you need [APM](https://docs.datadoghq.com/containers/kubernetes/apm/?tab=helm) (profiling)

All you need to add

```
        ad.datadoghq.com/CONTAINER_NAME_TO_MONITOR.check_names: |
          ["openmetrics"]
ad.datadoghq.com/CONTAINER_NAME_TO_MONITOR.init_configs: |
          [{}]
ad.datadoghq.com/CONTAINER_NAME_TO_MONITOR.instances: |
          [
           {
              "prometheus_url": "http://%%host%%:5000/internal/metrics",
              "namespace": "my_springboot_app",
              "metrics": [ "*" ]
            }
          ]
```

replace `5000` with the port of the container listening. again this is required to push Prometheus/openmetrics to datadog.

If you just need logs, no need for any extra fancy stuff, just `containerCollectAll: true` this is enough for logs collection.

**APM**

You need add JAVA agent, add this in the dockerfile

```
RUN wget --no-check-certificate -O /app/dd-java-agent.jar https://dtdg.co/latest-java-tracer
```

and then you need to update `CMD` to let the agent collect tracing/apm/profiling

```
java -javaagent:/app/dd-java-agent.jar -Ddd.profiling.enabled=$DD_PROFILING_ENABLED -XX:FlightRecorderOptions=stackdepth=256 -Ddd.logs.injection=$DD_LOGS_INJECTION -Ddd.trace.sample.rate=$DD_TRACE_SAMPLE_RATE -Ddd.service=$DD_SERVICE -Ddd.env=$DD_ENV -J-server -Dhttp.port=5000 -jar sfdc-core.jar
```

[trace_collection_java](https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/trace_collection/dd_libraries/java/?tab=containers)

Comment: Thank you ! I think I understand now, but what exactly check_names is supposed to do ? Is it only mean to be a tag ? 

Only to be sure, for example I want to get the JMX metrics so I suppose I have to install a cluster agent with version "latest-jmx" and configure some annotations on the pod and it's good, did I understood correctly ? (

https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/java/?tab=docker )

Comment: no, that's for docker, if you have auto-discovery this would enough `ad.datadoghq.com/<CONTAINER_IDENTIFIER>.init_configs: '[{"is_jmx": true, "collect_default_metrics": true}]'
        ad.datadoghq.com/<CONTAINER_IDENTIFIER>.instances: '[{"host": "%%host%%","port":"<JMX_PORT>"}]'`https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/guide/autodiscovery-with-jmx/?tab=containeragent

Answer (score 1):

> do I have to install both the datadog agent on the nodes + the datadog agent on the pods to reach springboot

In order to get logs and metrics shipped to datadog, the daemonset datadog agent pods are sufficient to scrape the spring boot pods. With the `openmetrics` integration for instance, just expose the metrics through a `/metrics` path.

In order to get traces, you need [to use the datadog java tracing library](https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/trace_collection/library_config/java) and configure it, you can start by simply set this env var to `true` for the apps containers `DD_TRACE_ENABLED`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes Datadog Agent and Cluster Agent will give you specifics about the nodes and pods. Documentation: https://docs.datadoghq.com/infrastructure/livecontainers/configuration/?tab=helm

For specific app metrics, Spring boot metrics can be exported using netflix spectator api. see implementation https://docs.spring.io/spring-metrics/docs/current/public/datadog

If you are using dropwizard, see also: [Spring boot metrics + datadog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34398692/spring-boot-metrics-datadog)